# Need to add ReactiveFormsModule to Angular custom library, but does not seem possible

Tags: angular

I am trying to use reactive forms in my Angular custom library that I am building. I manually added @angular/forms to the library's package.json's peerDependencies as such:

```
{ "name": "abc-library"
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "7.1.3",
  "@angular/core": "7.1.3",
  "@angular/forms: "7.1.3"
 }
}
```

Then I added the following template code to my component:

```
template: `<form [formGroup] = "abcForm">...</form>'
```

When I try to build the component, I get the following error:

[image: Can't bind to formGroup]

I'm at a loss as to what to do because this is a library, not part of the main application. I already have Reactive Forms working great in my main application. When I checked online about this error, the resolution was to import ReactiveFormsModule into the NgModule, but since the custom library does not have something like app.module.ts, I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Please provide your `.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

A library consists of any Angular schematic you like.

I would recommend having your library split into various modules.

So, if you have a Component in your library that uses Reactive Forms, you can then import the ReactiveFormsModule in the respective module.

The module could be like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { YourComponent } from './your.component'
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  exports: [YourComponent],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

and then in the public-api.ts file

```
export { YouComponent } from './lib/components/your-module/your.component'
export { YourModule } from './lib/components/your-module/your.module'
```

Then in your main application, you can import the `YourModule` in any module is required to be.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late reply.

I had the same problem and got it to work.

My solution was to map the component that I am using the reactive form inside my root app.module.ts and then add it on the declarations part.

```
import { LoginComponent } from '../../projects/my-lib/src/lib/login/login.component';

   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     LoginComponent
   ]
```

It doesn't seem to work even if you import the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule inside your library, no idea why.

Hope that can help you as well